# Dynamic Paypal Payee with direct checkout

Tags: php, paypal

I'd like to have different Paypal payees depending on the URL being viewed and using direct checkout so the user never leaves my site.  So for example at example.com/brandA someone could buy a product that brandA is selling and brandA gets paid, and at example.com/brandB someone could buy a product that brandB is selling and brandB gets paid.  Can I do this all through an API where all I need to specify is the payee email address?  Or does each payee need to set up a Paypal Payments Pro account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're processing the payments using Payments Pro (PayFlow or DoDirectPayment) then each seller would need Pro enabled on their own account, and you'd need to have them setup Permissions or use the Permissions API to make API calls on their behalf.

If you go with Express Checkout you can just set the PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter to the email address of the PayPal account you'd like the money to fall to.  That will work without any permissions necessary.

Note:  the n in the parameter name would be a 0,1,2,etc. depending on how many payments were included on the order.  With a single payment you would just use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=some@emailaddress.com